# Python Turtle Will Not Draw Circles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I'm making a snowman in python turtle for a coding class, but when it's drawing the buttons, they just don't draw. I've syntax checked it, and looked over, and I don't get why they don't draw. Here is my code

```
import turtle

turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.speed(100000)

#circle1
for i in range (36):
  turt.forward(18)
  turt.right(10)

#circle2
for i in range (36):
    turt.forward(12)
    turt.left(10)

  
  #circle3
turt.penup()
turt.goto(0,228)
turt.pendown()
for i in range (36):
    turt.forward(8)
    turt.right(10)
    
#eyes
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-7,200)
turt.pendown()

for i in range(36):
  turt.begin_fill()
  turt.forward(1)
  turt.right(10)
  turt.end_fill()
  
turt.penup()
turt.goto(20,200)
turt.pendown()
  
for i in range (36):
  turt.begin_fill()
  turt.forward(1)
  turt.right(10)
  turt.end_fill()
  
  
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-5,175)
turt.pendown()

turt.right(90)

for i in range (18):
  turt.forward(2)
  turt.left(10)
  
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-3,100)
turt.pendown

for i in range (36):
  turt.forward(2)
  turt.right(10)
  
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-3,80)
turt.pendown

for i in range(36):
  turt.begin_fill()
  turt.forward(2)
  turt.right(10)
  turt.end_fill()
```

Comment: Please do not add random text to your post to get around the quality filter message: “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details”. Instead, improve your question by including _meaningful_ information about the issue or issues facing your implementation. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add parentheses at the end of **pendown** method.
Try this code now:

```
import turtle

turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.speed(100000)

# circle1
for i in range(36):
    turt.forward(18)
    turt.right(10)

# circle2
for i in range(36):
    turt.forward(12)
    turt.left(10)

# circle3
turt.penup()
turt.goto(0, 228)
turt.pendown()
for i in range(36):
    turt.forward(8)
    turt.right(10)

# eyes
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-7, 200)
turt.pendown()

for i in range(36):
    turt.begin_fill()
    turt.forward(1)
    turt.right(10)
    turt.end_fill()

turt.penup()
turt.goto(20, 200)
turt.pendown()

for i in range(36):
    turt.begin_fill()
    turt.forward(1)
    turt.right(10)
    turt.end_fill()

turt.penup()
turt.goto(-5, 175)
turt.pendown()

turt.right(90)

for i in range(18):
    turt.forward(2)
    turt.left(10)

turt.penup()
turt.goto(-3, 100)
turt.pendown()

for i in range(36):
    turt.forward(2)
    turt.right(10)

turt.penup()
turt.goto(-3, 80)
turt.pendown()

for i in range(36):
    turt.begin_fill()
    turt.forward(2)
    turt.right(10)
    turt.end_fill()
```